# vim: highlight Folds change only background color

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I have commented out the

```
"hi Fold …
```

line in my current vim-colorscheme (xoria256 modified), but when I edit there is still (an even uglier) syntax highlight. I looked in the syntax file for the specific filetype - but there was no Fold highlight too. Now I don't know where to look for a "default syntax highlighting".

In the end I just want to have folds with foreground color as specified by syntax and just the background changed. Maybe I am thinking to much and there is a plain easy way to do that.

ps: i tried to leave off the `guifg` and `ctermfg` part to no success.

Comment: I don't know of a `Fold` highlight group. There is `Folded`, which is used for colouring closed folds (i.e. the line of foldtext). Is this what you mean?

Comment: sorry of course i meant `Folded`

Comment: at the end I have to confess I am dumb: after conversation with the maintainer of VimOrganizer (which was the cause for this question), I know that within the repository there is a patch for that feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid that doing so is not possible (at least without touching Vim's source code). The text in the fold line is computed and not part of your file, which means that it will not be processed like the rest of the text/code and it will be only applied the `Folded` highlighting group. That's why you get a single foreground color when you comment out the `hi Folded` line.

Comment: damn - i hoped there would be sthg. easy like linking a syntax definition. but thanks - so I know i don't have to search anymore, which leaves time for real work